# Write command working one way?

Tags: write

I want to communicate with my girlfriend through the write command. She's on a mac, I am on a debian laptop. I did the next steps:

1. `adduser haly`
2. `apt-get install openssh-server`
3. `systemctl start ssh`

Then she logins with `ssh haly@my ip address` (we are both connected to the same wifi) with the given password.
In our terminals we both do `mesg y` and I do `write haly`. She can see everything I write, but I cannot see anything she writes. What is wrong?

Thanks

[Editing to have a more complete question]

This is me:

```
murphy@eva02:~$ who
murphy   tty2         2018-12-17 22:58 (:0)
haly     pts/1        2018-12-17 23:25 (192.168.0.9)
murphy@eva02:~$ mesg y
murphy@eva02:~$ write haly pts/1
las rosas son rojas, el cielo es azul ...
```

She receives the last line in her terminal (after logging into `eva02` and doing `mesg y`). But If she tries `write murphy tty2` the write program seems to work in her terminal, but I see nothing in mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong; write is unidirectional:

> Any further lines you enter will be copied to the specified user's terminal.  If the other user wants to reply, they must run write as well.

... so she must `write your-username` in order to `write` back to you.

You may be thinking of the more-interactive `talk` utility; on Debian, `apt install ytalk` will get you started.

Comment: Yeah, the man doc on write says that  "If the other
     user wants to reply, they must run write as well." She does but I see nothing on my end.

Comment: With `talk` I cannot communicate with her (the program stays forever on "Checking on invitation on caller's machine")

Comment: Yes, write is unidirectional, but if she `writes` to me I receive nothing. `talk` seems better but did not work... `ytalk` on the other hand worked pretty well. Thanks

Comment: After she does `write murphy`, does she type another line (and hit Enter)?

Comment: Yeah, we tried it...but nothing. Obviously I did `mesg y` as well. There has to be something wrong with `write` and `talk`, because there was no problem at all with `ytalk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try having her add your device name. You can use who, w or finger to get this information. Usage: write username devicename , see if that helps...

Comment: Not working. `write haly pts/0` gives the same behavior: she receives my messages, I do not receive anything.